# query that executes too long (25 mins)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, compatibility

I have this query on a linked server

```
Select a.PawnMainID into #ExistingID 
from Beautifly.BIOS_PAWN.dbo.tblPawnMain a
inner join Transactions.tbl_PawnMain c
on a.PawnMainID = c.fld_PawnMainID
inner join Reference.tbl_BranchRowVersions b
on cast(a.[PawnMainID]/1000000000000 as decimal (38,0)) = b.fld_ID
where (a.StatusID between 3 and 5)
AND a.RowVersionBo > b.fld_MaxRowVersion
```

and it takes forever to finish while other codes seemed to be normal at all can you help me identify the problem? is my code note efficient enough? if so how can i improve it?

the picture below shows my execution plan having re remote query a cost of 99%!
[image: PIcture]

i also want to ask if my code is optimized? if not how can i optimize it?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur your right im also looking at the cast with division but that's the only way i can join it to `Reference.tbl_BranchRowVersions` im just tapping to other databases i do not have the rights to look or edit their indexes i also think that their index are not maintained that's why my query took very long to finish.

Comment: Looks like all of the cost is involved with executing the query at the remote server. Linked server queries can be very tricky to optimize, and your options are quite limited - have you considered flipping the order of the first two tables and using `INNER REMOTE JOIN`? Or pulling all of the remote data into a local #temp table (with better supporting indexes) and performing the join against that?

Comment: @AaronBertrand no i havent can you help me do it? im just a newbie in SQL so if you can provide me some code on which i can start to study i would appreciate it very much

Comment: @Sonam used my ideas in an answer so maybe they can help you with more specific code.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for your help i hope Sonam would provide me with codes to study..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query to remote server is always expensive, as first it will establish the connection, query the data, return the result and then close the connection. So, here to make the query faster the easiest option is, fetch the data from the remote server in a temp table and then execute the query.

Comment: And adding an index to the temp table if there is a large number of rows would then help as well.

Comment: how would i do that? can you provide me some codes? im sorry im just a newbie in SQL.

Comment: would i select * all data from the remote server into a #temptable before i run my query above?

Comment: It looks like you only need one column, so no, I wouldn't use `SELECT *`.

Comment: You only need to select the data which you are going to use in the query. I think your query should be: Select a.PawnMainID
from Beautifly.BIOS_PAWN.dbo.tblPawnMain a where (a.StatusID between 3 and 5)

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code was a little of a pain to read, but I'll take a stab: the JOIN statement between `tblPawnMain` (a) and `tbl_BranchRowVersions` (b) are not [SARGABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable):

```
ON CAST(a.[PawnMainID]/1000000000000 AS decimal (38,0)) = b.fld_ID
```

SQL Server does not know the results of the CAST until it evaluates the function. Hence it must grab every row from `tblPawnMain` and `tbl_BranchRowVersions`. The thin arrow coming out of the Remote Query operator tell sme that the result set is small, but the JOIN may be expensive because they are huge tables and a CROSS JOIN was performed.

Try to run this from the `Beautifly` server directly and post your execution plan:

```
SELECT a.PawnMainID, b.fld_ID
FROM Beautifly.BIOS_PAWN.dbo.tblPawnMain a
INNER JOIN Reference.tbl_BranchRowVersions b
ON CAST(a.[PawnMainID]/1000000000000 as decimal (38,0)) = b.fld_ID
WHERE (a.StatusID BETWEEN 3 AND 5)
AND a.RowVersionBo > b.fld_MaxRowVersion
```

If you you constantly joins those two tables using that CAST, it may be worthwhile to add a column on `tblPawnMain` that is `CAST(a.[PawnMainID]/1000000000000 as decimal (38,0))` and put an index on it. Your JOIN will then be SARGEABLE.

Comment: thank you for your response but i do not have the rights to alter the tblPawnMain to add another column i was just tapping in their data..